# OS major build number in Linux Machine

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, operating-system

In Python, how to fetch OS Major build number for Linux and Windows.

Below code can give us the Major Windows build number under version parameter.

```py
>>> import platform; platform.uname()
uname_result(system='Windows', node='LP-213289619', release='10', version='10.0.22621', machine='AMD64')
```

`Major Windows OS Build Number -> 22621`

What is the equivalent value for Linux when we execute same code in Linux.

```py
>>> import platform; platform.uname()
uname_result(system='Linux', node='ubuntu', release='4.15.0-202-generic', version='#213-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 19:19:12 UTC 2023', machine='x86_64', processor='x86_64')
```

`Major Linux OS Build Number -> ?`

Or any other common way to print OS build number for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Windows and Linux may have different notion of `Major OS Build Number`. What do you want to do with that number on Linux ?

Comment: @Philippe, what is the notion for Linux Major OS Build Number can u just give me an example and none of the above uname_result contain build number in case of Linux?

Comment: @Arunkumar G - How do you imagine to maintain a Linux build number when everyone can build Linux?

Comment: @Armali I'm new to Linux, not sure what is this build number in Linux
So you mean that there will not be any build number for Linux?

Comment: I mean there can't be a universal build number. Of course everyone who builds a kernel can maintain a personal build number, and indeed in your example this could be `#213`.